# How to check if Object is instanceof HashMap<?,?>[] in Java?

Tags: java, hashmap

I have in java an array of HashMaps

```
HashMap<String, String>[] convertTags = new HashMap[1];
HashMap<String, String> tag = new HashMap<>();
tag.put("key", "test-tag");
tag.put("value", "test-value");
convertTags[0] = tag;
```

And in another class, I pass this convertTags object to a function that takes in a generic Object. Based on the type of object, I want to run different code. However, when I have an if statement to check the instanceof the array of HashMaps, it doesn't seem to recognize my convertTags object.

```
public static void function (Object obj) {
...
   if (obj instanceof HashMap<?, ?>[]) {
      //do stuff
   }
}
```

Am I missing something? Calling .getClass() on convertTags object returns `class [Ljava.util.HashMap;`

Comment: Recall that generics in Java are largely a compile-time only phenomenon.  The run-time type of `Hashmap<String, String>[]` is that of `Hashmap[].class`, which is what `getClass()` returns.  If you need more type information about the hashmap, you can consider passing *type tokens* for its elements.

Comment: Also if you have code that takes an `Object` and does a bunch of `instanceof` checks, you might want to consider a different approach. It's quite primitive and clumsy, and there's probably a better way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When doing type checks with `instanceof`, you cannot use a generic type as the check: you must use a raw type.  The reason for this is simple:  most of the generic type information is erased at compile-time and no longer exists at run-time.   To the JVM at run-time, these types are the same: `List<T>`, `List<String>`, `List<Hashmap<E>>`, and `List`.  If Java allowed the use of generic types for `instanceof` operations, serious type errors could result.

In fact, it is not strictly correct to allow operations like:

```
if (obj instanceof Hashmap<?,?>[]) { ...
```

The compiler allows this because unbounded wildcard types are the only type of *reified* generics that exist in Java.  Many authors discourage the use of unbounded wildcards in this situation because they may imply that the use of other (non-reifiable) generic types is valid.  Rather, this is the uncommon situation where it is best to use the raw type:

```
if (obj instanceof Hashmap[]) { ...
    Hashmap<?,?>[] map = (Hashmap<?,?>[]) obj
        :
        :
```

Because the type has been checked, the cast is legal and no compiler warning will be emitted by the above snippet.

If run-time information is needed about the types in the `Hashmap`, you can consider two approaches (that can be mixed):

- generifying `function()` to take type parameters for the keys and/or values
- passing `Class<T>` objects as run-time *type tokens* for the types of the keys and values.